# inserting data to database class method

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send data to the database (trying a new method) but the message is printing but the data is not in the database

config.php

```
public function insertData_product ($total,$quantity,$card_id) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product_order (ord_total,ord_qty,card_id) VALUES (:ord_total, :ord_qty, :card_id)";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['ord_total' => $total, 'ord_qty' => $quantity, 'card_id' => $card_id]);
    echo "data inserted to order table";
    }

  require_once 'config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $card_id = $_POST['card_id'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $field1 =  $_POST['field1'];
        $field2 =  $_POST['field2'];
        $field3 =  $_POST['field3'];
        $field4 =  $_POST['field4'];
        $field5 =  $_POST['field5'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $total = 0;
        $total = $price * $quantity;

        $config = new database();

        $config->insertData_product ($total,$quantity,$card_id);


    }
```

Comment: You don't actually seem to check if the `execute` was successful?